# To get current ip address in c# from client side

Tags: c#, ip-address

In my application,i need to get the ip address of user who loads the application

I tried various way to get ip address.But when try to load application ,not getting current ip address.

```
 protected string GetIPAddress()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[0];
            }
        }

        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

string ipAddress=Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString()

string ipAddress=(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != null) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress : null;




  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            ipAddress = wc.DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org/");
        }
```

Comment: What are you calling `mobile`? A cellphone? And on what network?

Comment: "not getting correct ip address". How are you measuring that? The IP address of mobile devices is not necessarily publicly visible, and can change at any time, and likely sits behing some kind of Network Address Translation layer to reduce the number of public IP addresses that the mobile provider must provision.

Comment: Define "incorrect".

Comment: In system or mobile,In both in some cases not getting correct ip address.

Comment: How to get the correct IPV4 address

Comment: @Achu_L Can you provide an example of a "good" ip address vs a "bad" one? What indicates to you that you are not receiving the correct IPv4 address. Do you understand that it might not be possible to get this information due to the constraints mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: not getting current ip address of user

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var isConnected = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
    if(isConnected){
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how this is different to the code supplied above? In particular the line `string ipAddress=Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString()` is functionally identical to the code you've posted. This adds nothing (except a different kind of exception).

Comment: Not getting correct IP may relate to not get the network connection. First, check if the network connectivity `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() `

Comment: @Achu_L So what IP address are you getting.

Comment: Getting ip address in this format sometimes 2405:204:71c7:d1b5::1e9b:90a5.I need to get ipv4 address